# Можно ли пропускать строки в MySQL?

Tags: mysqli, mysql, запрос

```
$array=array(1,3,4,20,55,88,125,1000);
$string=implode(',',$array);
$init=8;

$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE set='$init' AND status IN ($string) LIMIT 2");
```

Можно ли пропускать строки в случае уже существующего вхождения определённого значения? То есть, если первая строка

```
id=1
set=8
status=1
```

, вторая

```
id=2
set=8
status=1
```

, а третья

```
id=3
set=8
status=3
```

, то можно ли как-нибудь модифицировать запрос, чтобы он достал записи с id=1 и id=3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GROUP BY название_столбца** возвращает первые строки из выборки с уникальными значениями в указанном столбце.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE set='$init' AND status IN ($string) GROUP BY status LIMIT 2");
```